# Is There Any Way To Force An Element Sized Using An Intrinsic Ratio To Fill Its Container Vertically As Well As Horizontally?

Tags: html, css, layout, sass, intrinsic-ratio

Sassmeister [here](http://sassmeister.com/gist/b3a36dc4c26985b9cbd8)

If an element's dimensions are defined using an [intrinsic ratio](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/):

Sass:

```
body,
html,
.Wrapper 
{
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.VideoContainer
{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;

  &.Sixteen-Nine {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  }

  &.Four-Three {
    padding-bottom: 75%;
  }
}

.VideoContainer iframe,
.VideoContainer object,
.VideoContainer embed
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="VideoContainer Vimeo Sixteen-Nine">
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/109777141?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=090909" class="js-only" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Is there any way to contain it so that it resizes to the hight of its container?**

It will currently resize to the width of its container while maintaining its aspect ratio, however, even with a wrapper that defines an explicit height, it will overspill the container if the width of the wrapper compared to its height is greater than its aspect ratio.

I need to support IE9+ and I don't want to use JavaScript

Comment: Please show your html.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs Added the HTML.

Comment: sorry it's hard for me to understand the behavior here, but have you tried adding a `display: block;` in the `.VideoContainer iframe` element?  I would try that, and get rid of the `width: 100%;` element.  Other than that, maybe a screen shot would help?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs I've added a link to a Sassmeister so you can see it in action. I've also added a link to an A List Apart article on intrinsic ratios.

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me if this is what you had in mind?

```
.Wrapper 
{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
 }

.VideoContainer
{
  position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  &.Sixteen-Nine {
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  }

  &.Four-Three {
    padding-bottom: 75%;
  }
}

.VideoContainer div
{
  height: 100%;
}

.VideoContainer div iframe{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="VideoContainer Vimeo Sixteen-Nine">
    <div>
      <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/109777141?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;badge=0&amp;color=090909" class="js-only" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't make any difference. When the Wrapper is resized vertically, the video overspills the container. Besides, `Wrapper` is a `div` and therefore `block` by default.

Comment: divs are block elements, but are styled as `display: block;` only by convention; that's an important distinction.  Using the code above in the Sassmeister console, changing the size of the window scaled the video size for me, keeping it in the container.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome but the result is the same in Safari and Ffox. You have bypassed the intrinsic ratio and set the video to fill its container. This is not the same as is fitting in the container while maintaining aspect ratio: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/316978/aspect.jpg